# is the following sentence correct? "Please select each articles condition."

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, business-language

A customer should choose the condition for each "article".
"articles" is also the plural form of "article".
so is "Please select each articles condition." correct, or should i use something like "...article's..."?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you mean 'the condition which each article is in', yes, you need the possessive _article's_.

Comment: thanks, if you post it as answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean 'the condition which each article is in', yes, you need the possessive *article's*.